# NIS: rpc.yppasswdd segfaults on Xenial

Tags: 16.04, nis

NIS functions well except for yppasswd. When a user tries to change password using yppasswd on a client, if s/he enters the wrong Old Password, then the rpc.yppasswdd daemon on the NIS server segfaults. Searching online, I see that a similar bug was reported for Trusty, but it also seems to have been fixed in Xenial. Is the bug still around in a different form, or do I seem to be doing something wrong?

Messge from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
[125555.251005] rpc.yppasswdd[17581]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f2514294e16 sp 00007fff331e3a58 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f2514147000+1c0000]
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in 16.04 (xenial) in the package `nis - 3.17-34ubuntu3` The bug appears to still exist in Trusty.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nis/+bug/1204530

Of course as a workaround you could simply enter the correct password.

Comment: Thanks, I checked version of nis on my system and it is the version you mention. The bug report you pointed me to doesn't specifically speak of entering wrong old password. For me the crash is specific to that - if correct old password is entered, it seems to work fine. I filed a bug report with the crash files ...